# Several TextFields and search Button in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have several TextFields and a search Button in Vaadin. I would like to execute my search button with Enter key, no matter in which TextField I am. First I initialize all my components and set

```
searchButton.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER);
searchButton.setImmediate(true);
```

which works all times except the first time after opening my VerticalLayout.

I also tried [Both ENTER shortcut and TextArea in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820117/both-enter-shortcut-and-textarea-in-vaadin), to set ENTER key to every single TextField, which works anytime, except the first time, when I open my VerticalLayout.

If I do the same for ESCAPE key it works all the times.

Have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.