# Vaadin ComboBox blur event gets triggered when enter pressed

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to add a `Enter` key shortcut listener to a `ComboBox`. I only need the shortcut to work when the `ComboBox` is focused. I used the approach described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822623/1015678) answer.

```
    combo.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focus(FocusEvent event) {
            combo.addShortcutListener(shortcutListener);
        }
    });
    combo.addBlurListener(new BlurListener() {
        @Override
        public void blur(BlurEvent event) {
            combo.removeShortcutListener(shortcutListener);
        }
    });
```

What it does is, adding the shortcut listener when the combo box got focus and removing the shortcut listener when combo box lost focus.

This works well for `TextField`s but does not work for `ComboBox`. The reason is, whenever I press enter on the `ComboBox`, blur event gets called instead of shortcut listener getting called. Since shortcut listener is removed when blur event gets fired, shortcut listener never gets fired.

Why does combo box trigger a blur event when enter is pressed? How can I get this fixed?

Comment: Wrap the combobox in a Panel and then assign a shortcut listener to it. It should work fine.

Comment: @Patton It worked. Please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above in comments, wrap the the combobox is panel and add shortcut listener to it. This should work.

Why? When you add a shortcut listener by default the scope of this shortcut listener is added to enclosing Panel/Window/UI(basically single component containers).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this help? At least in vaadin 7 it makes no difference, because you need blur event notifier on combobox and therefore blur will clear panel's shortcut listener....